# Change font size universal for Bootstrap without mucking with internal css

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, xpages, xpages-extlib

I am using a bootstrap theme for my application in Xpages (using the Xpages Bootstrap theme included). The size of everything seems way too big to me; this app is for web (and maybe the Lotus XPiNC client.

How can I change the size without changing modifying any of the Bootstrap css?

Comment: The short answer: use CSS. Bryan, please update your question with a screenshot and some example code. I do not find the Bootstrap font to be too big. The default font size in Bootstrap is 14px. Check with your browser's developer tools what font size you get (and check that you have reset zoom)

Answer (score 1):

You can override the default font size with some CSS, by changing the font size set on the body element:

```
body.xsp {
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

But that won't cover everything. There are likely to be a number of other font sizes you need to override for other elements, e.g. buttons

```
.xsp .btn {
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

This will be noticably easier to do using Bootstrap 4 when it is released. In v4 there is a font-size set on the `html` element (default is 16px). Then every font-size set in the rest of the Bootstrap CSS uses `rem` values (root em). This sets the font-size of everything relative to the font size of the root html element. Thus you can easily change the font size throughout your application by making one CSS change to alter the font size of the html element. This will also allow for responsive typography, so you can scale your font size up/down depending on the device size. Check out [this link](https://scotch.io/bar-talk/whats-new-in-bootstrap-4) for more info about this feature in Bootstrap 4; look for the "New Unit (rems) for Typography" section.